# Why do I get a notification for an edit I did?

Tags: support, edits, live-refresh

I edited [How do I change a widget's markup?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29204/how-do-i-change-a-widgets-markup) to change the tag used (I reverted the change I previously made), and I got a notification about a new edit; when I clicked on it, I discovered [the edit was mine](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/29204/revisions).

> [image: screenshot]

As I was the author of the edit, should not a page refresh be done, in this case? I should see the notification only when somebody else edited the question while I was viewing it, or answering to it.