# Why are one's own changes excluded from auto-update?

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, live-refresh

When you open the same question in two tabs in your browser (or one using the mobile app and one the website), and you edit the post, it doesn't show a notification on the other tab that the post has updated, as it always does when someone else does.

It seems that all edits come through except your own. I sometimes make mistakes because I think I edited a post but it doesn't show anything. When I refresh the page it suddenly shows the changes.

Is there a reason this doesn't work? If not, is it possible to show the notification when I edit a post too?

Comment: Note that the WebSocket notifications for both your own edits and own comments are received in the page where you are just viewing the question or tabs where you make the edit or place the comment. However, notifications caused by your own global user ID are explicitly filtered out by the in-page JavaScript prior to acting on the notification. It's *much* easier to just filter everything out when it was done by your UI than it is to determine if the specific change indicated in the WebSocket notification has actually been applied to the page yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this may have been due to a fix for [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130187/why-do-i-get-a-notification-for-an-edit-i-did) a while back.

Basically, right after the realtime feed feature was implemented, there was a bug where when you made an edit, that *same* page would show the edit notification. This was because there was a slight delay between you clicking the submit button and the realtime feed that powers the page updating it. A similar issue also occurred for comments: it would show "show 1 more comment" immediately after one posted a comment.

I think they disabled the realtime feed notification altogether for one's own edits (and comments), in order to resolve this issue. But this completely disregards the case where the same post is open in another window/tab. I don't know how easy it would be to re-implement the realtime feed to regard those, but somehow exclude the same saved edit (or comment) from triggering it on the same page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be hard but not impossible. Basically, the Javascript has to know which events have "already happened" in the client view, and which events have not happened, and when it gets notified of an event that it already knows about, it should ignore it. But I imagine  this is easier said than done because eventual consistency is awful.